# Git untracked file 1

Tags: git, macos, version-control

In my git repositories, an empty file simply named `1` somehow appears from time to time

```
❯ git status
On branch main
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/main' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    1
❯ cat 1
❯ ls -l 1
-rw-r--r--  1 gerard  wheel  0 Jun 27 12:50 1
```

The file belonging to the `wheel` group kind of suggests running `pip install -r requirements.txt` might be related, but I don't understand what the purpose of this file could be. I can perfectly gitignore it and/or remove it when is shows up, but it has become a very tedious thing to do often.

Anyone has seen this behavior, have any clue why the file is created and how to prevent it? Thanks!

Comment: Sometimes this happens if either you, or a script, ran a command that contains a syntax error and something that was  intended to be an argument ends up generating a file instead. There is one developer on my team that occasionally has an empty file named `-w` in his PRs which I have to remind him to delete. (I don't know what command he runs to accidentally generate the `-w` file.) Every once in a while I mess up a command in bash and get a syntax error, and maybe a few minutes later I'll notice that the output of my command generated a file. Maybe yours is a mistaken redirect like `>1`.

Comment: thanks for your reply! that kinda makes sense, except that this happens in all my projects, both work and personal, and I've seen it appear as soon as I clone the repo and only run `pip install -r requirements.txt` :(

Comment: If you know the steps to reproduce it, I would try [svlasov's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76568013/184546) of locking down the file, and then perhaps the `pip install` command will fail, and possibly error out and provide more details which may be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

That could be due to a common typo when somebody wanted to redirect standard error to standard output but forgot `&`, e.g. `2>1` instead of `2>&1`. If so, empty `1` file indicates that the command did not print any errors.

If you want to get a clue what created it, limit permissions to the file:

```
chmod 0 1
sudo chown root 1 # optional, use sudo to remove the file later
```

So next time when something tries to create/modify/read this file, it will fail and hopefully log the error.

Comment: That's a great idea for troubleshooting when it happens again.